# Why won't the Rule work? And how to apply it to a combination of variables?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, assumptions, associations, rule

I want to convert SI to Gaussian units given vectors:

[image]

```
Subscript[Ε, si] = {Ex, Ey, Ez};
Subscript[B, si] = {Bx, By, Bz};
Subscript[S, si] = 1/Subscript[μ, 0] (Subscript[Ε, si]/[Cross]Subscript[B, si])
Subscript[S, si] /. {Subscript[B, si] -> Subscript[B, si]/c}
```

why doesn't the change apply?

Also, I have this horrible vector I'm trying to simplify in a similar manner (and apply certain conditions to it such as $B_z E_x = B_x E_z$):

[image]

```
Subscript[Ey, g] = γ (Ey + v/c Bz);
Subscript[Ez, g] = γ (Ez - v/c By);
Subscript[By, g] = γ (By - v/c Ez);
Subscript[Bz, g] = γ (Bz + v/c Ey);

Subscript[S, p] = c/(4 π) (Subscript[Ε, si]\[Cross]Subscript[B, si]) /. {Ey -> Subscript[Ey, g], Ez -> Subscript[Ez, g], 
    By -> Subscript[By, g], Bz -> Subscript[Bz, g]};
Subscript[S, p] /. {v -> c Tanh[ζ], Bz Ex -> Bx Ez, 
    Tanh[ζ]/Sqrt[Sech[ζ]^2] -> 
    Sinh[ζ]} // FullSimplify
```

I see that Rule doesn't work on combinations of variables, at least not in this expression for some reason. I tried inputting `Bz Ex - Bx Ez /.Bz Ex -> Bx Ez` on a separate line and it returned `0`, like it should. Is there some trick to it? Why is it being finicky?
As far as trig functions, I tried TrigReduce, but it didn't do anything. The square root of a square thing always bugs me. I also tried using assumptions with $\zeta>0$ and $\text{sech}(\zeta)>0$, but again to no avail. Is there a way to reduce that as well? And is there a general way to change certain chunks of expressions like that?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but something to be aware of when using `ReplaceAll` is that the expression is evaluated *before* replacing, so after evaluation MMA can't find any instances of what you're trying to replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is as it should be. In the first instance, you want a separate rule for each element of the list. For that, you can use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html):

```
Subscript[Ε, si] = {Ex, Ey, Ez};
Subscript[B, si] = {Bx, By, Bz};

Subscript[S, si] = 
  1/Subscript[μ, 0] (Subscript[Ε, si]*
     Subscript[B, si]);

Subscript[S, si] /. Thread[Subscript[B, si] -> Subscript[B, si]/c]
```

> $$\left\{\frac{\text{Bx} \text{Ex}}{c
>    \mu _0},\frac{\text{By}
>    \text{Ey}}{c \mu
>    _0},\frac{\text{Bz} \text{Ez}}{c
>    \mu _0}\right\}$$

For the second issue, you probably shouldn't be using rules but `Assumptions` passed to `FullSimplify`. You can also try [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Eliminate.html). But that depends on what you actually want to achieve with the "certain conditions" you speak of - i.e., which variables you want to eliminate.

Replacement rules are based on patterns, and if the pattern as written doesn't appear, the rule doesn't apply. So the rule for $B_z E_x$ is probably not what you want. Here is how to rewrite it so it gets used:

```
FullSimplify[
 Subscript[S, p] /. {v -> c Tanh[ζ], Bz -> Bx Ez/ Ex}]
```

> $$\left\{\frac{c \gamma ^2
>    \left(\frac{(\text{Bx}
>    \text{Ez}+\text{Ex} \text{Ey}
>    \tanh (\zeta )) (\text{Bx}
>    \text{Ez} \tanh (\zeta
>    )+\text{Ex}
>    \text{Ey})}{\text{Ex}^2}+(\text{
>    By} \tanh (\zeta )-\text{Ez})
>    (\text{By}-\text{Ez} \tanh
>    (\zeta ))\right)}{4 \pi
>    },\right.\\
>    -\frac{c \gamma  \tanh (\zeta
>    ) (\text{Bx} \text{By}+\text{Ex}
>    \text{Ey})}{4 \pi },\\\left.\frac{c
>    \left(\gamma  \text{Ex}
>    (\text{By}-\text{Ez} \tanh
>    (\zeta ))-\text{Bx} \gamma 
>    \left(\frac{\text{Bx} \text{Ez}
>    \tanh (\zeta
>    )}{\text{Ex}}+\text{Ey}\right)\right)}{4 \pi }\right\}$$